# Laravel - Multiple relationships Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I just started learning laravel, and i'm struglling with Eloquent Relationships! 
I have two tables, they are both multi-level:

Paginas-

- IdPagina PK
- name
- Parent

example:

```
  idPagina  name   parent 
  1          A      Null
  2          B       1
```

Categorias -

- IdCategoria PK
- name
- Parent
- IdPagina - FK

  Example:

> ```
> idCategoria       name    parent    idPagina
> 1                 C       Null      2
> 2                 D       1         2
> ```

Well...so I want to get something like this:

- A - Parent
- B - (A's)Child
- C - (B's) Child
- D - (C's) Child

Then I have Paginas model:

```
  class Paginas extends Eloquent{    

     public function children() {         
         return $this->hasMany('app\paginas', 'parent', 'idPagina');
         } 

          public static function tree() {
         return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(1, 10, 'children')))->where('parent', '=', null)->get();

       }}
```

---

And categorias model:

```
class Categoria extends Eloquent{




 public function children() {
 return $this->hasMany('app\categoria', 'parent', 'idCategoria');

    }

     public static function tree() {

 return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(1, 10, 'children')))->where('parent', '=', null)->get();

 }
}
```

and now I just want to join both tables!

**EDITED**

Well, i just added the codes Stephen Lewis suggested! 
But now i can't get the multi-level as i want to, here is the blade code

```
@foreach($paginas as $pagina)
  <h1>{{$pagina -> nomePag}}</h1>
   @foreach ($pagina -> children as $child)
     <h3>{{$child -> nomePag}}</h3>
     @foreach($pagina -> categorias as $categoria)
         {{$categoria -> nomeCat}}
     @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

well, i just can't get the $categoria related to the $pagina -> children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the `Categoria` class:

```
public function pagina()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Pagina', 'idPagina');
}
```

You can also specify the other side of the relationship, by adding this to the `Pagina` class:

```
public function categorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categoria', 'idPagina');
}
```

Further information on how to work with Eloquent relationships is available [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent).

Comment: Thanks for the code! 
hope you can help me now, i edited the question ;)

Comment: The innermost loop should be `@foreach $child->categorias`

Comment: Okay, forget about the nested loop for a second. Do the different relationships work on their own? Does `$pagina->categorias` return a collection of categories, `$categoria->pagina` return a single page, and so forth?

Comment: Yes everything is working fine except the nested loop... the problem is that im not linkin the 3rd loop and the 2nd loop....and not figuring out how to do that

Comment: Well the link should be that you use `@foreach $child->categorias` in the third loop (from what I can tell), but you said that doesn't work. Is Eloquent returning any errors?

Comment: no, eloquent doesn't return any error, and i'm using Wamp so i cant see the errors.... i'm just wondering at the tree (), don´t i need to call categories()?

Comment: I'm confused Marcus, you're not _using_ the `tree` method anywhere in your code.

Comment: yes, i'm calling it in the route file :   $paginas = Pagina::tree();

Comment: Right, you didn't mention that. Change the method to `return static::with('children')->has('parent', '<', 1)->get();`

Comment: doesn't work with "has" so i changed with to "where", just getting the same output